# How to fix nodemon "block-scoped declarations..." error?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, nodemon

This is my package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "pro-mern-stack",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "first init",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon server.js server.js",
    "compile": "babel src --presets react,es2015 --out-dir static",
    "watch": "babel src --presets react,es2015 --out-dir static --watch",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "Yusuf",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "mongodb": "latest"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.2"
  }
}
```

I'M TRYING TO RUN `npm start` TO START THE WATCHER BUT I KEEP GETTING THIS ERROR:

```
> nodemon server.js server.js

    C:\MERN\pro-mern-stack\node_modules\nodemon\lib\monitor\run.js:356
        let sig = signal.replace('SIG', '');
        ^^^

    SyntaxError: Block-scoped declarations (let, const, function, class) not yet supported outside strict mode
        at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
        at Module._compile (module.js:373:25)
        at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
        at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
        at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
        at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
        at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
        at Object.<anonymous> (C:\MERN\pro-mern-stack\node_modules\nodemon\lib\monitor\index.js:2:8)
        at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
        at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)

    npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.10240
    npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start"
    npm ERR! node v4.5.0
    npm ERR! npm  v2.15.9
    npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
    npm ERR! pro-mern-stack@1.0.0 start: `nodemon server.js server.js`
    npm ERR! Exit status 1
    npm ERR!
    npm ERR! Failed at the pro-mern-stack@1.0.0 start script 'nodemon server.js server.js'.
    npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the pro-mern-stack package,
    npm ERR! not with npm itself.
    npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
    npm ERR!     nodemon server.js server.js
    npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
    npm ERR!     npm bugs pro-mern-stack
    npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
    npm ERR!
    npm ERR!     npm owner ls pro-mern-stack
    npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

    npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
    npm ERR!     C:\mern\pro-mern-stack\npm-debug.log
```

I'm running with powershell on windows 10. I've tried installing globally, didn't work. Also have the latest version of nodemon. Please, how can i fix this? I've reinstalled nodemon several times, keep getting the same error, even when I run it directly in the console. Thanks!

Comment: can you remove one server.js from the start script, its just nodemon server.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see issue in the npm script. You should just update it to nodemon server.js

Comment: I tried that but I keep getting the same exact error

Comment: okay. I see from logs the node vetsion that you are using is v4.5.0 which is causing the issue. This version does not support let , const etc without strict mode. You should update your node version. It will solve the issue. or you can just apply strict mode in the code.

Comment: Thanks. I'd already tried applying strict mode, didn't work but updating node solved the problem. Thank you.